# Missing Something Easy (Button OnClick Causing Null Pointer)

Tags: android, button, android-widget, nullpointerexception

Suddenly my buttons cause null pointer exceptions.  I have not changed any code in this activity class.  I have been up most of the weekend trying to pin this down.  I get null pointer exceptions in both the emulator and on device.

This is a simple screen with buttons.  I could easily scrap this and write new code, but would like to know what has caused this issue.  If not, I will just write new code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MainActBtn);

b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Error is here

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Any help?

Comment: have you add MainActivity activity in manifest file?

Comment: Add your layout xml or make sure you put the right `id` and done this process after `setContentView()`

Comment: Yes. The error is actually pointing to the onclicklistener line

Comment: whaat does error say when point on it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a fresh clean and build of your project. I got this error too in the past, caused by a changed `R.class` Resource class, but the static references in the using classes weren't properly replaced by the incremental java compiler, so the resources are no longer found.

Comment: I knew it would be something extremely easy.  After a complete clean and rebuild the R resources were recompiled.  Eclipse sometimes does things that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I think You are not getting Null Pointer Exception because of the Button click just because of the declaration of the button..

You can check before writting the onClickListener..

```
if(b1==null)
 Log.i("Null","Null");
```

**The Problem is may be in setting the XML view or also check the button you are using is defined in the same xml you are using in setContentView.**

After this all, also Clean and Build your project.

Comment: I have all ready added the line in order to check before I posted the question.

Comment: Frank, I had to uncheck Build Automatically, and the clean the project, and then recheck Build Automatically.